# Is there a way to get the max memory used by a task in mesos?

Tags: scala, mesos

**Context:**

I implemented a `Scheduler` in Scala based on the [Mesos Scheduler Interface](http://mesos.apache.org/api/latest/java/org/apache/mesos/Scheduler.html).

All tasks are perfectly orchestrated.

**Expectations:**

Now, I would like to be able to monitor the max memory consumed by completed tasks.

I expect to perform this monitoring task inside my implementation of [`Scheduler.statusUpdate()`](http://mesos.apache.org/api/latest/java/org/apache/mesos/Scheduler.html#statusUpdate-org.apache.mesos.SchedulerDriver-org.apache.mesos.Protos.TaskStatus-) method, for every task with [`TASK_FINISHED`](http://mesos.apache.org/api/latest/java/org/apache/mesos/Protos.TaskState.html#TASK_FINISHED) state.

**Question:**

In this method, a [`SchedulerDriver`](http://mesos.apache.org/api/latest/java/org/apache/mesos/SchedulerDriver.html) and a [`Protos.TaskStatus`](http://mesos.apache.org/api/latest/java/org/apache/mesos/Protos.TaskStatus.html) are provided.

So, is there a way to retrieve the max memory used by the corresponding task from a [`SchedulerDriver`](http://mesos.apache.org/api/latest/java/org/apache/mesos/SchedulerDriver.html) and a [`Protos.TaskStatus`](http://mesos.apache.org/api/latest/java/org/apache/mesos/Protos.TaskStatus.html)?

Answer (score 2):

Mesos exposes information about task statistics in [`slave(1)/monitor/statistics`](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/endpoints/slave/monitor/statistics.json/). You need to scrape this endpoint on each agent and aggregate the response to get the maximum value for a given task.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of isolation your Mesos agent is configured with, e.g. `cgroups/*` or if you are using the Docker containerizer, you might consider running an external service on your agent hosts that collect and aggregate memory and other runtime statistics for you. For instance, you could use a collector daemon such as [cadvisor](http://github.com/google/cadvisor) to monitor your tasks and then [ship](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/blob/master/docs/storage/README.md) those metrics on to a persistent datastore where they can be queried in a flexible way.