# Individual Apache Mesos taks real resource usage monitoring

Tags: mesos, apache-aurora

Does anyone knows if it's possible to monitoring the real (not allowed, configured by aurora), resources usage that a task in Mesos is doing?

I've look into all the Mesos HTTP Endpoints but I've only been able to found configuration information (resources I had fixed into the .aurora file).

Thanks to all.

Edit: I've actually scraped all the /master/.. /slave/... Endpoints but it doesn't give real resources usage information, it only gives you information about reserved resources for each task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the max memory used by a task in mesos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46094057/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-max-memory-used-by-a-task-in-mesos)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46112948/1387612)